# Developing WLST scripts with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, jython, pydev, wlst

We are in the process of developing several WLST (WebLogic Scripting Tool) scripts and we would like to setup a development environment.

Has anybody managed to configure Eclipse PyDev (or another plugin) to support it? Do you know any other alternative?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the latest version of OEPE allows to create and run WLST scripts. Latest version is located here...

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html

Comment: http://www.ora600.be/news/wlst-scripting-oracle-enterprise-pack-eclipse-oepe for a quick start. Thank you for the info.